# Drove with parking break on

Tags: chevrolet, damage, parking-brake, aveo

I just started driving and I was driving in the rain today so I was already anxious. I went about 30 minutes going 50-60. The total distance was 20 miles. After I fixed the parking break the breaks seemed to be working fine but could there be a lot of damage? For reference I have a 2011 chevy aveo ls.

Comment: That is a possible problem with only partially applying the emergency brakes. Either put it on maximum/ forcefully ,or don't put it on.

Answer (score 0):

You say you fixed the parking brakes, so they should be fine. The rain helped cool the brakes, although that's a long ride with brakes engaged. It still might of cooled them enough to prevent damage. If the brakes work fine and there is no vibration or pulsing in the brake pedal while braking, you should be fine. But it would be wise to have the brakes inspected, if you have any concerns.